# Objects are being released when compiling to macOS X

Tags: macos, delphi, osx-snow-leopard, delphi-xe5

I'm rewriting an app for OS X (which is running in a VirtualBox). When I compile all my objects are released. I'm a novice programmer and this is my first mac app, so I'm not even completely sure this is the problem.

I have installed RAD PAServer to OS X. In this terminal I get the following error messages:

```
 __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4237a10 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x664dc3c of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

These are just 2 examples of a large variety or error messages, which all start with __NSAutoreleaseNoPool().

RAD Studio XE-5 doesn't give any error messages when compiling to OS X  or a Win32 target platform.

I hope to have informed you sufficiently.

Update:

I have added a TCalendarEdit to my form. When I click on it in OS X, the program crashes and I get the following runtime error message in the PAServer terminal:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x127e99d4: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

Update 2:

It seems not every object is released. This code works:

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label1.Text := 'bladibla';
end;
```

And when I recreate TCalendarEdit functionality this way, all is fine:

```
var
  CalendarButton: TButton;

procedure TForm4.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Calendar1.Visible := true;
  Calendar1.Position.X := Button7.Position.X;
  CalendarButton := Button7;
end;

procedure TForm4.Calendar1DateSelected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CalendarButton = Button6 then
    Button6.Text := DateToStr(Calendar1.Date);
  if CalendarButton = Button7 then
    Button7.Text := DateToStr(Calendar1.Date);

  Calendar1.Visible := false;
end;
```

Comment: What exactly is producing these error messages? These are runtime messages? Do you have any code?

Comment: In the example of the TCalendarEdit, I actually have no code (see my update)

Comment: Does the same code work on Windows or is it OS X specific?

Comment: @birger On windows everything works fine. I only have problems on OS X